# Menu Goes left side (approx 20px in chrome) when click on menu in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in menu flickering in bootstrap when i click on any of the menu it goes **left side 10-20px in chrome** and then page loads so what is the issue in it. It's working perfectly in FIrefox and safari but in **chrome it's not working**. I didn't change any css or js of bootstrap so i share cdn link of bootstrap js and css. **My live website's url** is explained below.

Url : http://cmexpertiseinfotech.com/experttheme/index.html

CSS : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Js : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

HTML Code of menu:

```
<nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-mi">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand padd_btm" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="theme.html">Themes</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.html">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="cyan" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-fw" title="Copy to use lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**EDIT :**

Css changes as of transition (I also Tried with change in all the transition but i have updated question only with -webkit-transition)

```
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a 
 {
           color: #fff !important;
           background-color: #158fa1 !important;border-radius: 5px;
           -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease;
           -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
           transition: all .4s ease-in-out
 }
```

Comment: I think `transition` inside `.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a` selector is problem. Apply specific transition for properties for which you need by replacing `transition: all` to `transition: color 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease` etc.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman thank you for the reply . i tried with it. first i changed the all transition of .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a and then i also tried with particular for webkit also but it's not working i have updated my code with css which i have change please see the edited question.

Comment: Why `transition` property values are different for `-webkit` and others? Use same values for all `transition` properties.

Comment: i tried with same also but i have updated question with only webkit. even i remove other transitions also but it's not working

Comment: Hmm, Check by disabling Google Fonts and others if you are using any. It might be issue with fonts. First browser shows them in websafe fonts untill fonts files are downloading and when they finish downloading it displays them with new fonts which takes less space and you see flickering effect.

Comment: oh great..  Thank you brother it's perfectly working. please add your answer with separate answer so i can upvote it :)

Comment: you are welcome, I've added answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, This flickering effect is because of Google and other fonts if there are any in your web page.

When your page loads, browser uses default web-safe fonts to show your content. Meanwhile it starts downloading fonts from Google and other servers. Each font has its own characteristics i.e width and height of each character is different in different fonts.

Default web-safe font in your case is taking more space so when fonts are completely downloaded and changed on your webpage, you see flickering effect.

To fix this issue, you can use a pre-loader that will be visible untill all your files are downloaded completely and your web page is fully ready to the users.